# How to add increment value with div id javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add set of input field in my form area with JavaScript. my code works correctly.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10;
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap");
        var add_button      = $("#add_field_button");

        var x = 1;
        $(add_button).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){
                x++;
                $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="form-group"><label>City</label><select class="form-control" id="bcity" name="bcity[]">' +
                '<option value=" ">Select</option>' + '</select></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text

            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
```

But I want to add value of x with `id="bcity"` .
I am trying but give error.

Comment: what error it gives ???

Comment: You're not even making an attempt to use `x` anywhere? You are just appending a hardcoded HTML string.

Comment: `id="bcity' + x + '"` would give you bcity1, bcity2, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## jQuery

Here you go, you have to concat the strings in different pieces in order for this to work dynamically in your loop.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var max_fields = 10;
     var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
     var add_button = $("#add_field_button");

     var x = 1;
     $(add_button).click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         if (x < max_fields) {
             x++;
             $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="form-group"><label>City</label><select class="form-control" id="bcity' + x +  '" name="bcity[]">' +
                 '<option value=" ">Select</option>' + '</select></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
         }
     });

     $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text

         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).parent('div').remove();
         x--;
     })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice you're doing `x--` when removing, so you can have duplicated names, so I would suggest to use couple of vars:

```
var x = 1;
var fields = 1;
```

`x` used exactly as @Harben suggest, and `fields` controlling number of total fields:

```
if (fields < max_fields) {
    x++;
    fields ++;

    $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="form-group"><label>City</label><select class="form-control" id="bcity' + x +  '" name="bcity[]">' +
        '<option value=" ">Select</option>' + '</select></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
}
```

But, after, when removing:

```
$(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { 
    //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    fields--;
});
```

In this way you will avoid overlapping names and you will be able to reference all the created fields when necessary with a simple `JQuery` function.